# Cannot access immediate location in Android

Tags: android, location, locationmanager

Guys This is very important question. I found lots of developers having same problem and i am facing same. I want to get immediate location on my device but it looks really difficult.

I have tried following technique, It works but very slow, after may be 15 minutes i get location,

```
MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 0;
MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 0;

    Boolean isGPSEnabled = 
    locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if(isGPSEnabled) {
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                              MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, pendingIntent);
    }
    Boolean isNetworkEnabled = 
    locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    if(isNetworkEnabled) {
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, pendingIntent);
    }
```

Then I tried this, It does not work also.

```
public String setCriteria() {
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
        criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
        criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
        criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_MEDIUM);
        return locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
}
```

and I am also confused about getLastKnownPosition(). It always return last logged position. which of course i am not interested .  Kindly help me how can i access address immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use LocationClient instead of Locationmanager. The fused location is much simpler and easier to understand. refer to the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html).
getlastKnownLocation() provided by LocationManager may present you with expired or old location values.
If you are interested in the best location available, use getLastLocation() which returns the best most recent location currently available.It provides location with the best accuracy available while respecting the location permissions specified in the manifest.